# Remove a td cell containing specific text from being counted

Tags: jquery

```
   var donotcountS = 'td.player:contains(S)';  

  $(data).find('td.two_column_layout .report').each(function (index, element) {
  if ($(this).find("td.player:not("+donotcountS+")").length !== +RequiredStarters && $(this).attr("id") !== "InvalidLineup")
```

I am trying to count all td.player cells , except for those where children span class contain a specific letter. Here is what i have. I set a var "donotcountS" , but i have 2 questions.

1. How can i make the var also use a true or false declaration so i can decide whether i want to count or not count , based on true or false setting ?
2. how can i add a 2nd var called donotcountP , so i can also remove span warning with text P , not to be counted as well, also with true/false so i can turn both on or 1 or the other ?

Example HTML

```
<table>    
 <caption><span><a></span></caption>    
  <tbody>    
   <tr><th class="player">TEXT</th><th>TEXT</th></tr>    
   <tr><td class="player"><a>TEXT</a></td><td>TEXT</td></tr>    
   <tr><td class="player"><a>TEXT</a></td><td>TEXT</td></tr>    
   <tr><td class="player"><a>TEXT</a></td><td>TEXT</td></tr>   
   <tr><td class="player"><a>TEXT</a>(<span class="warning">P</span>)</td><td>TEXT</td></tr>      
   <tr><td class="player"><a>DO NOT COUNT THIS TD CELL HAVING SPAN WARNING WITH "S" TEXT</a>(<span class="warning">S</span>)</td><td>TEXT</td></tr>    
  </tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: Don't use quote with `contains`. I did a small example here of something similar  https://jsfiddle.net/epumf3bw/

Comment: That works but i need to be more specific ("td.player:not(td.player:contains(S))")   , i need td.player that has span.warning that contains "S"

Comment: upload complete html file which contains all the classes that you have used as selectors so that we can better understand the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to skip counting a `td` element that contains a specific text here is what you can do.

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/g1a3dnn4/)

The above fiddle uses the below function,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $("td").each(function () {
       var tdText = $(this).children("span.warning").text();
        if(tdText != "S"){
            count++;
        }
    });
    alert(count);
});
```

**UPDATE 1:** From what I understand you are generating a table dynamically and once it is generated you want to count `td` which does not contain a specific text. If this is what you want then you can use the above function after your table is generated as follows,

```
$.get('http://%HOST%/%YEAR%/options?L=%LEAGUEID%&O=06', function (data) {
    $(data).find('td.two_column_layout .report').each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(this).find("td.player").length !== +RequiredStarters && $(this).attr("id") !== "InvalidLineup") {
            var target = $("#InvalidLineup").find("tbody");
            $(this).find("span a").each(function () {
                var className = this.className;
                if (clazz[className]) {
                    return
                }
                clazz[className] = true;
                target.append("<tr class='oddtablerow'><td>" + $(this)[0].outerHTML + "</td><td class='lineupalert'><a class='lineuplink' href='http://%HOST%/%YEAR%/options?LEAGUE_ID=%LEAGUEID%&O=02&%FRANCHISEID%'>Submit Valid Lineup</a></td></tr>");
            });
        }
    });

    //insert the function to count specific td here
    var count = 0;
    $("td").each(function () {
        var tdText = $(this).children("span.warning").text();
        if(tdText != "S"){
            count++;
        }
    });
    alert(count);

});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
($(this).find("td.player:not(donotcountOUT)").length
```

donotcountOUT is a variable so I guess it should be written as,

```
($(this).find("td.player:not("+donotcountOUT+")").length
```

**UPDATE 3:** You can use multiple `:not()` and create another variable named `donotCountP` and use it as follows,

```
var donotcountS = 'td.player:contains(S)';  
var donotcountP = 'td.player:contains(P)';

$(data).find('td.two_column_layout .report').each(function (index, element) {
  if ($(this).find("td.player:not("+donotcountS+"):not("+donotcountS+")").length !== +RequiredStarters && $(this).attr("id") !== "InvalidLineup")
```

Comment: @MShack I think an easy way here could be to let the td with span 'S' to append to the new table, after it is appended we can remove those particular td's from the new table. How about that?

Comment: @MShack check my update 2 and tell me does it solves the issue?

Comment: Saumil , that is working now. I updated my question for my 2nd part of original question i needed help with. TY !